# How to Stop Timer when User Collides with an Object ? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have set a timer, it is working great but i cannot let it stop when user collides with another object.

```
Text text; float theTime;

public bool timer;
void Start()
{
     text = GetComponent<Text>();
}
void Update()
{
     if (timer == true)
     {
         theTime += Time.deltaTime;
         string seconds = (theTime % 60).ToString("0");
         text.text = seconds;
     }
}
}
```

I cannot manage to stop timer when user collides with any object.

I have tried calling reference methods on internet but did not work.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What methods have you tried? Is this an issue about collision detection, or your collision handler?

Comment: Instead of stopping the timer you have other options you can use for debuging the issue.  First of them are start a new time and then difference the two timers.  Second try a break point and see if the timer stop is even being hit.

Comment: i could not find how to reference timer script to collider script.

i am aware of i need to create another script for enemy objects however i could not find out a way to connect those different scripts.

or is there any other way :/ ?

i need to stop timer when enemy objects hit my player. thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure where you're stuck but after there is a collision, set `timer` to `false`. This can be one in the `OnCollisionEnter` or `OnTriggerEnter` function depending on the type of collision. If you're new to physics in Unity, see [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/physics) tutorial. You need to watch **#1** an **#2** to understand colliders.

If your collision type is not a trigger:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    timer = false;
}
```

If using trigger:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    timer = false;
}
```